# MYSQL ENUM ; Invalid Syntax

Tags: mysql

I am executing an SQL command that I have executed many other times in other environments but cannot a reason for this syntax error.

This is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    customer_id INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    DOB DATETIME,
    Gender ENUM('M', 'F'),
    city_code (6) NOT NULL
)
```

I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near 'M'

If anybody has a pointer of something I am blatantly missing, please show the way.
I'm using Microsoft MySql 2014 Express Edition

Comment: `city_code (6)`  it need to declare type.

Comment: ENUM is not a function  ..  add also a space between ENUM and  (..)

Comment: i changed the RDMS from MySQL to MSSQL tag as `ENUM` is a non SQL Server (MSSQL) datatype and the error is related to  SQL Server (MSSQL)  and not MySQL..

Answer (score 2):

When seeing `Gender ENUM('M', 'F')` and the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near 'M'.

I am pretty sure that you are mixing up RDMS SQL dialect syntax here.

As SQL Server does not know the `ENUM` datatype, this is a MySQL datatype.

This works in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    Gender ENUM('M', 'F')
); 

INSERT INTO Customer (Gender) VALUES('M');
INSERT INTO Customer (Gender) VALUES('F');


# : Error: WARN_DATA_TRUNCATED: Data truncated for column 'Gender' at row 1
#INSERT INTO Customer (Gender) VALUES('A');
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iV7m6F1Y58DsTfJeq2gmN/0) ..

One option to simulate/emulate this on SQL Server is with a `CHECK` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    Gender CHAR(1) CHECK(Gender IN ('M', 'F'))
); 

INSERT INTO Customer (Gender) VALUES('M');
INSERT INTO Customer (Gender) VALUES('F');
```

See [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/080915/1)

Using

```
INSERT INTO Customer (Gender) VALUES('A');
```

would cause an error

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint column 'Gender'

**Note**

Also `city_code (6) NOT NULL` is missing a datatype.

Answer (score 0):

1. `city_code (6)` it need to declare type.
2. `IDENTITY(1,1)` is other rdbms function not mysql,you can use `AUTO_INCREMENT`

> ```
> Create Table Customer
> (
>     customer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>     DOB DATETIME,
>     Gender ENUM('M', 'F'),
>     city_code varchar(6) NOT NULL
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=190ed54c2f7a1b903b7dfb8865a3ca19)*

Comment: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near 'M'.`  is a SQL Server (MSSQL) related error not a MySQL error..

Comment: *"yes,you're right. but his title is mysql."* yes always check before answering if the tag and title is correct or makes sense with the rest of the question..